# INSERT and SELECT sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert

If I insert a value with an order by name like this.

```
+------------------+
|  Table: example  |
+------------------+
|  Name   | Value  |
+---------+--------+
|   A     | 153    |
|   B     | 10     |
|   C     | 20     |
|   D     | 50     |
|   E     | 100    |
+---------+--------+
```

When I select the value with a query

```
select * from example
```

or

```
select * from example limit 2
```

without a  `where`, `order by` or `group by`, is the order of the result defaulted to the insert order??

Thanks,

Comment: mysql select order generally pulls in insertion order but it is not guarenteed.

Comment: see this link - [**DEFAULT ORDER**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: It probably won't sort by Value. MySQL may attempt to use an auto-increment id if present, but you _must_ use `order by` if you need to guarantee the order.

Comment: No. The 'order' is unpredictable and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski If value is a unique key then it absolutely WILL sort by value !!